# Static table in peewee

Tags: python, database, enums, peewee

I want to store an enum in the database, according to [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305148/why-would-you-store-an-enum-in-db).

So let's say, I have a Gender enum and a Person model. I want to do a select like `Person.select().where(Person.gender == Gender.MALE)`
This can be achieved by creating a GenderField in Person as described [here](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#custom-fields). But the gender won't be in the database as a table, and I want the Person to have foreign keys to the Gender table.

So how can I store static Gender data in the database, then query the Person table by the enum values?

Answer (score 0):

You can, as part of the table creation process, populate the gender table:

```
class Gender(Model):
    label = CharField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        database = db


def create_schema():
    # Use an execution context to ensure the connection is closed when
    # we're finished.
    with db.execution_context():
        db.create_tables([Gender, ...], True)
        if not Gender.select().exists():
            defaults = ['MALE', 'FEMALE', 'UNSPECIFIED']
            Gender.insert_many([{'label': label} for label in defaults]).execute()
```

The only reason to make Gender a table in this example, though, would be if you plan to dynamically add new Gender labels at run-time. If the set of values is fixed, my opinion is you're better off doing something like this:

```
class Person(Model):
    GENDER_MALE = 'M'
    GENDER_FEMALE = 'F'
    GENDER_UNSPECIFIED = 'U'

    name = CharField()
    gender = CharField()

# Then, simply:
Person.create(name='Huey', gender=Person.GENDER_MALE)
Person.create(name='Zaizee', gender=Person.GENDER_UNSPECIFIED)
```

Comment: The problem with the first one is that it is Stringly-typed, and I have to query Genders every time, by their name.

The second one won't work for me. I need the Gender to be a table, because it is used in other relations too. In this silly example, I want to label the restrooms with gender.